# Creating offline map tiles for JMapViewer

Tags: java, openstreetmap, jmapviewer

I want to create offline map tiles for JMapViewer from an image. How may I be able to achieve it? What are the tools used to generate those tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to reach that goal. All of them make use of an external toolchain:

**1. Offline renderer**
This is a bit more complex, as you need to use a renderer, a map style and OSM data packages to render your own map tiles on your box. A first simple way is to make use of  [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) as it's very easy to configure and comes with styles. More advanced, you can setup a whole OSM rendering stack (Mapnik, PostgreSQL DB, osmosis, ...) so please see the tutorial at www.switch2osm.org

**2. Tile downloader**
This is pretty easy. There are different tools to download tiles from the official servers:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category:Tile_downloading
But please keep in mind that this machines are donated and should not be stressed by just a few single users. So the speed needs to be very moderate and respect the TUP:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy