# JMapViewer adding tiles of a region on Panel

Tags: jmapviewer

Hi there i'm using **JMapViewer** to show maps in my swing app and I've successfully created a panel with map tiles on it but these map tiles are of a particular area used in demo source of Map Viewer, i'm confused about how can i show the tiles of some particular area i want. Just like **Google maps** i want to show some location of my country (Pakistan) in the maps and i don't know how can i do it.
Secondly, Please explain what are Layer's and Layer Group in JMapViewer? Just an idea.

Edit: how can i download tiles of Islamabad region and then add them to maps.
What i've learnt from demo is this:

```
private void loadMapTiles(){
     map().setTileSource(new OsmTileSource.Mapnik());
     map().setTileLoader(new OsmTileLoader(map()));
}
```

But this shows some specific area they have set to.

I've downloaded JTileDownloader but i'm confused about the url thing because i don't now where to get the url of some specific area.

Answer (score 1):

1. Given a `JMapViewer` named `map`, something like this should display Islamabad:

   ```
   Coordinate c = new Coordinate(33.7167, 73.0667);
   map.setDisplayPosition(c, 10);
   ```
2. [`org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.Demo`](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/src/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/Demo.java), included in the distribution, is a complete example that illustrates how to use `Layer`. Click the *Tree Layers Visible* checkbox to see the effect.

Addendum: Here's the result using [MapQuest-OSM](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map) at 11x zoom; [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org) seems to work, too. If no `TileSource` includes the tiles you want, you may need one of the approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22805302/230513).

[image: Islamabad Mapnik]

Comment: how can i download tiles of Islamabad region and then add them to maps. What i've learnt from demo is this:

private void loadMapTiles(){
     map().setTileSource(new OsmTileSource.Mapnik());
     map().setTileLoader(new OsmTileLoader(map()));
}
But this shows some specific area they have set to.

I've downloaded JTileDownloader but i'm confused about the url thing because i don't now where to get the url of some specific area.

Comment: If no `TileSource` includes the tiles you want, you may need one of the approaches mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22805302/230513).

Comment: Sir i'm very new to JMapViewer, All i know is the demo code which comes with the release.
I want exactly what you have shown in the above image but for bahria Town lahore pakistan
And i want to restrict my panel to show only this area's map.
where do i get the code of above mentioned frame so that i may study it and try to understand what is going on.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're having trouble; please edit your question to include a complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a `Coordinate` for Lahore.

Comment: sir as i have added the map of Pakistan now, how can i restrict my mapPanel to view only the map of this area and no other area.

Comment: You can customize the `DefaultMapController`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24688091/230513).